# In Jekyll, can we group multiple collections inside the same folder?

Tags: collections, jekyll

In config.yml, I define my collections like this:

```
collections:
  music:
    output: false
  dancing:
    output: false
```

The problem is I will have lots of collections and they will clutter my root Jekyll folder.

Is there a way to group all the collections into a folder, named for example, _collections?

So, I would have:

```
_collections
     _dancing
     _music
     ....
```

Comment: Hey Dany, would you consider to accept an answer? [Jussi's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428493/2989289) was pretty enlightening for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This **is now possible** (I'm running Jekyll 3.7.2, I'm not sure in which version this was implemented).

Here's how to do it: In your `_config.yml` you can define your collections as well as the folder for your collections. Let's take a look at an example on a client site I'm working on:

```
collections:
  events:
    output: true
  work:
    output: true
  jobs:
    output: true
  cases:
    output: true
    permalink: /work/:name
collections_dir: pages
```

The `collections_dir: [your_folder_here]` will tell Jekyll to look into that folder for collections. My folder structure in development is as follows:

```
pages/
  ...
  _events/
  _work/
  _jobs/
  _cases/
```

And in the compiled site it's as follows:

```
...
events/
jobs/
work/ (contains both "work" and "cases" collections)
```

One thing also that wasn't asked, but I found to be useful, was that you're able to output **different collections into a same folder**. In my case I had a client website on which there were two types of work samples: client cases and general examples. We wanted to separate them for better maintenance but also show them in the same folder. To achieve this you can simply define a permalink for the collection. In our case we put permalink for the cases to appear in the `work` folder (`permalink: /work/:name`).

Hope this helps!

This is also present in the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/)

Answer (score 4):

Answer is no. Your collections folder must be at the root of your root folder.

Even if you name you create a collection in _collections/_music folder, and set it up like this :

```
collections:

  collections/_music folder:
    output: true
```

Jekyll ends up looking for your collection in `_collections_music folder` (without any slash) because of path sanitize process.

See jekyll code in [collection.rb](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/3.0-stable/lib/jekyll/collection.rb#L101), [site.rb](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/3.0-stable/lib/jekyll/site.rb#L374) and [jekyll.rb](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/3.0-stable/lib/jekyll.rb#L152)

Answer (score 4):

Nothing prevents you to use subfolders in your collection.
(Note: this is not an answer to your question but a possible workaround)

So as a workaround you could have just one collection: say `_arts` for example and organize your folders like:

```
_arts
     dancing
     music
     concerts
     .....
```

to list them separately you can use:

1. a FrontMatter variable in your files `category: dancing` **when you have a output** and check this for a dancing only list for example.

   ```
   {% for project in site.arts %}
   {% if project.category == 'dancing' %}
   ....
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. or check the path when you have **no output** for the collection

   ```
   {% for project in site.arts %}
   {% if project.url contains 'dancing' %}
   ....
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

This could slowdown your build if you have hundreds and hundreds of items inside.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible since [this issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/6331) was merged.

> User configures as:
>
> ```
> collections_dir: my_collections
> ```
>
> Then we look in my_collections/_pizza for the pizza collection, and my_collections/_lasagna for the lasagna collection.

Comment: Correction: This will be possible come version 3.7.0. 'Gather your collections3.7.0
You can optionally specify a directory to store all your collections in the same place with collections_dir: my_collections
Then Jekyll will look in my_collections/_books for the books collection, and in my_collections/_recipes for the recipes collection.' or visit: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

Comment: Will this affect the two "default" collections, i.e., `_pages` and `_posts`?

Comment: @iBug Yes. From the docs: "Be sure to move drafts and posts into custom collections directory. If you specify a directory to store all your collections in the same place with `collections_dir: my_collections`, then you will need to move your `_drafts` and `_posts` directory to `my_collections/_drafts` and `my_collections/_posts`."